# When does bootstraping apply?

Tags: bootstrap

When considering bootstraping method, what are the conditions on the underlying population distribution and sample size?

Most places I've looked only describe the method itself, without giving much justification. I understand that a general theorem-like proof might not exist at all, however, there probably are at least some considerations.

Comment: The domain of application of the bootstrap is very well characterized and from the beginning has been on a solid theoretical footing.  See the classic [Introduction to the Bootstrap](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Bootstrap-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/0412042312) by Efron & Tibshirani.

Comment: @whuber looks promising, thanks!